# validation with personnalite messages html5

Tags: javascript, html

I need detect the error type from a input and send a personalized message to input, when the user when the user does not comply with the format sends me the personalized message, but if you do not enter any data the browser sends me the message by default. validity.valueMissing don't work.
this is my code.

JS

```
var email = document.getElementById("email");
    email.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
      if (email.validity.typeMismatch) {
        email.setCustomValidity("Formato incorrecto.");
      }if(email.validity.valueMissing) {
        email.setCustomValidity("Este campo es requerido");
      }else{
        email.setCustomValidity("");
      }
    });

  }
```

HTML

```
<label class='col-sm-3 control-label'>
        <font color="red">*</font>
        Correo electronico</label>
<%= f.email_field :email, :class => 'form-control', :id=>'email', :required=>true %>
```

Comment: There's no way to answer your question without seeing where you set (or in your case, don't set) the value of `validity`. This question also has nothing to do with Rails. Please don't use a tag because it's incidental to your projects, but not the question at hand.

Comment: @MarsAtomic, `validity` is a feature of HTML5 and is not set by the application.  This value is set by the browser according to the validation rules on the element.